# Can "have not" be used when you talk about your experience?

Tags: present-perfect

"I have never been to Disneyland."

This is about my experience, isn't it?

"I have not been to Disneyland."

Can this sentence have the same meaning?  Or does that mean that I am thinking of going to Disneyland but have not completed the action yet?

Comment: Both of them are about experience, or more precisely, about a lack of experience. Neither is about the future.

Answer (score 3):

They mean the same thing.  Neither one implies that you are thinking of going.  *Never* is for emphasis here.